# Dynamically add images to a prototype custom cell

Tags: ios, tableview, custom-cell

I have a UIViewController with an embedded tableview.
The prototype cell has been customized (and subclassed) to add a "slider" effect started by a pan gesture recognizer.
I've followed this tutorial to do it: https://github.com/spilliams/sparrowlike
Inside the cell I've got two views, a front view that slides away, and a back view that stays there showing other controls.

Now I need to add an image to every cell, this image will be chosen between two images depending on a BOOL variable.

The problem is: if I add the image view programmatically, the image will be added to the cell and then when the user swipes away the front view, the image stays there.
So the image should be added to the front view, but I can't do it in the StoryBoard and add an outlet to it.

So the question is: should I put the code to retrieve the image in the custom cell subclass?
If so, where should I put it?
My "CustomCell" class implementation file looks like this at the moment:

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell
@synthesize frontView;
@synthesize backView;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {

}
return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
- (void)setupCell {
    if (yourBoolValueHere) {
        [[self frontView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:someImageName1]];
    } else {
        [[self frontView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:someImageName2]];
    }
    [[self view] bringSubviewToFront:[self frontView]];
}
```

Then, you can just call `[cell setupCell]` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.